# xcode copying project to another computer

Tags: xcode

I'm having problems copying a project over from one mac to another. The project compiles and runs fine after being copied, however xcode seems to have some duplicate of the same classes which seem to be invisible on the project browser on the left.

For example if I jump to definition on a variable I get 2 suggestions pop up. The top file when I look at its properties is relative to xcode folder (this is also the one that shows up in the class browser to the left). The second file which cant be seen on the browser has absolute path type in the properties.

Is there any way to get rid of this behaviour so its just looking at one file only like it originally was doing on the other mac? Its a bit problematic as I am never sure which one I am editing and they don't seem to update each other even though they appear to be the same file.

On a side note if I copy the copied project to another location then I get 3 etc files pop up in the jump to definition.

Comment: This is a question for http://superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually a good idea to either not copy the "build" folder (or delete it after you've copied everything over - only do this when Xcode is not running though).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what you need to do is this:
1.Duplicate your project. 
2.Open the copy w/the original ,but only the folder.
3.open the Projects files(not the tests the main files)
4.then Drag and drop the files into the xcode area.
5.Zip the folder and its done

its like that because it just removes the references but not the files they are all still there though so just add the references back into the file.